# How to get data from a cshtml form and write it to a txt file using Razor Pages c#

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am creating a Live Chat web page in Razor Pages with c#.

I have a cshtml form that contains the gui.

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.LiveChatModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "LiveChat";
    Layout = "~/Pages/_LoggedIn.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Live Chat</h2>
    <div id="enterName">
        Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" />
        <button id="btnName">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div id="currentName">
        Your Name:
    </div>
    <div id="supportName">
        Support Name: Jeff
    </div>
    Chat History
    <div id="messages">

    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="message" name="Message" cols="100"></textarea> 
<button id="sendMessage">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is use the C# model to get a value from the textarea that is sent and write it to a text file in the project folder.
Hope you can help.
Thanks

Comment: Your model @model Project.Pages.LiveChatModel should have a string property name Message and that will automatically bind the value of the textarea on the server side. You should submit a form to get the values on the server. What is not clear for you?

Comment: @st_stefanov Oh I see, and then in a post function I would write the data to the file using C#?

Comment: Sure. Let me make an answer with more details for youl

Comment: @st_stefanov Alright thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This describes the steps and the flow and should clarify the process and answer your question.

Model:

```
public class ChatModel
{
    public string Message{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
@model ChatModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessage", "MessageController", FormMethod.Post}))
{
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)
```

Controller:

```
public class MessageController : Controller

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMessage(ChatModel viewModel)
    {
var message = viewModel.Message;
// Code to save to file here
```

You have a model, a controller and a view.
The model declares the variables that will be used for binding.
In the View you declare your model and you set the properties of this model as shown above. It is 2 way binding, meaning that you can have values that come from the server initially and these values also go back to the server when you submit.

Example: if I set the value of property Message to "Hello, this is initial value". Then this will be shown to the client side.
Now if it is editable field, the user can change that value, e.g. "This is my message" and when the form that contains this element is submitted, the controller should have parameter of type `ChatModel`...then the ASP.Net engine will bind the values from the client side to the corresponding variables.

And yes...you will get the message value on the server and you can persist to anything you want, DB, file or transport further to another service...

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me, you made it more clear to understand!